# Optimization: Where to process data? Database, Server or Client?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I've been thinking a lot about optimization lately. I'm developing an application that makes me think where I should process data considering balancing server load, memory, client, loading, speed, size, etc..

I want to understand better how experienced programmers optimize their code when thinking about processing. Take the following 3 options:

- Do some processing on the database level, when I'm getting the data.
- Process the data on PHP
- Pass the raw data to the client, and process with javascript.

Which would you guys prefer on which occasions and why? Sorry for the broad question, I'd also be thankful if someone could recommend me good reading sources on this.

Answer (score 3):

Database is heart of any application, so you should keep load on database as light as possible. Here are some suggestions

1. Get only required fields from database.
2. Two simple queries are better than a single complex query.
3. Get data from database, process with PHP and then store this processed data into temporary storage(say cache e.g. Memcache, Couchbase, Redis). This data should be set with an expiry time, expiry time totally depends upon type of data. Caching will reduce your database load to a great extent.
4. Data is stored in normalized form. But if you know in advance that data is going to be requested and producing this data requires joins from many tables, then processed data, in advance, can be stored in separate table and can be served from this table.
5. Send as few as possible data on client side. Less HTML size will save bandwidth and browser will be able to render page quickly.
6. Load data on demand(using ajax, lazy loading etc), e.g a image is not visible on a page until user clicks on a tab, this image should be loaded upon user click.

Answer (score 3):

Two thoughts: Computers should work, people should think.  (IBM ad from the 1960s.)

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." --Donald Knuth

Unless you are, or are planning to become, Google or Amazon or Facebook, you should focus on functionality.  "Make it work before you make it fast."  If you *are* planning to grow to that size, do what they did: throw hardware at the problem.  It is cheaper and more likely to be effective.

Edited to add: Since you control the processing power on the server, but probably not on the client, it is generally better to put intensive tasks on the server, especially if the clients are likely to be mobile devices.  However, consider network latency, bandwidth requirements, and response time.  If you can improve response time by processing on the client, then consider doing so.  So, optimize the user experience, not the CPU cycles; you can buy more CPU cycles when you need them.

Finally, remember that the client cannot be trusted.  For that reason, some things *must* be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

So as a rule of thumb, process as much of the data in the database as possible.  The cost of creating a new connection to query is very high, so you want to limit it as much as possible.  Even if you have to write some very ugly SQL, performing a `JOIN` will almost always be quicker than performing 2 `SELECT` statements.

PHP should really only be used to format and cache data.  If you are performing a ton of data operations after every request, you are probably storing your data in a format that's not very practical.  You want to cache anything that is not changed often in an almost ready to server state using something like Redis or APCu.

Finally, client should never be performing data operations on more than a few objects.  You never know the clients resource availability so always keep the client data lean.  Perform pagination and sorting on any data sets larger than a few dozen in the back-end.  An AJAX request using AngularJS is usually just as quick as performing a sort on 100+ items on an iPad 2.

If you would like further details on any aspect of this answer please ask and I will do my best to provide examples or additional detail.